# Copying files based on date modified in batch file

Tags: scripting, batch-file, copy

I am trying to copy files from one directory to another using a DOS batch script. The files I want to copy are the 4 or 3 latest files. That number will be static, but yet to be determined. Is there anyway to copy based on date modified?

Thank you

Comment: xcopy source destination m-d-y is the closest I can find with batch. It'd be easier with vbsscripting, and you can find something close to what you need.

Answer (score 4):

You could:

1) have the `dir` command sort files in the descending order of date modified;

2) use the output of the `dir` command in a `for loop to copy the corresponding files;

3) count to 3 (or 4) in the `for` loop to limit the number of files copied.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "srcdir=D:\Source"
SET "tgtdir=D:\Target"
SET /A topcnt=3
SET /A cnt=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /A-D /OD /TW /B "%srcdir%"') DO (
  SET /A cnt+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  IF !cnt! GTR !topcnt! (ENDLOCAL & GOTO :EOF)
  ENDLOCAL
  COPY "%srcdir%\%%F" "%tgtdir%"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of using dir to sort the files. This should work nicely.

Comment: @Jack: Add the mask to the `FOR` line just after the `%srcdir%`, like this: `FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /A-D /OD /TW /B "%srcdir%\*.zip"') DO (`