# Batch file to copy a file based on date modified

Tags: batch-file

Folder : C:\data\PRODDB\dir

In the above folder files get created daily in the morning .I want to create a batch script which checks/identifies that folder for the latest file based on date and copy to other location ( d:\test).

eg: file created as backup_110513.DMP  11/05/2013

We will use a backup software to schedule a backup job to backup the files in the folder(d:\test) and after that particular file gets backed up from d:\folder, need to create another script which empties the folder d:\test.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying files based on date modified in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391835/copying-files-based-on-date-modified-in-batch-file). I found the duplicate simply by looking at the first two "Related" links to the right, which would have appeared as suggestions while you were typing your question. There are a few others which seem to be the same, as well. Please do at least a minimal search here before posting new questions; chances are quite good that the question (and an answer) have been posted before. :)

Comment: Hi Ken ,i did my search and used the same script which you mentioned in your comment .. but i wanted to write a script which also deletes/empties the files after they are backed up from the folder d:\test.

Comment: Then just modify that code to delete the files after copying them. SO is not a code writing service; you should be able to find answers here *similar* to what you're wanting to do, and then do some work yourself to make them do the rest. If you try, and run into problems, you can ask about those specific problems and we can try to help. :)

Answer (score 6):

This will do the copy part of the files with modification date of today

```
forfiles /P "c:\data\PRODDB\dir" /M *.DMP /D +0 /C "cmd /c copy @path d:\test"
```

Comment: ok got it ... if want all the files without extension .DMP .. just have to remove the /M *.DMP right ?

Comment: And the path is correct and there is a file in it with .dmp extension and this has been generated today?

Comment: Thanks MC ND. "/D +0" copies the files of present date right ? will schedule a batch job to run every morning  at 5 am using the above batch file script. After the file gets backed from the d:\test folder using backup software , need to run a script to empty the d:\test folder the same day. how to write that delete script ?

Comment: FORFILES /P "C:\test" /D +0 /C "cmd /c del @file"  This will delete the files in the c:\test folder created on that day.. right? what does del @file mean ?

Comment: You should better use `@path` than `@file`. `@file` is the filename (with extension), while `@path` is the full path of the file. Both are parameters from FORFILES that get replaced while processing command for each of the occurences found.

Comment: @MCND..Does `forfiles` work for a network path as a source ? if yes, please can you have a look at `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927807/move-all-files-created-today-from-network-location-to-local-drive`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  When the results you want are displayed remove the "echo.".
The goto is necessary so that we exit the loop immediately after copying the newest file.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir C:\data\PRODDB\dir /B /A-D /O-D') do echo.copy "%%a" d:\test & goto :Done
:Done
pause
```

Comment: it didn't work... i ran the batch file ,it asked for press any key to continue and nothing was copied to the other folder.

Comment: It won't copy anything as I wrote it.  As a matter of safety I only made it DISPLAY the copy command.  If the corrrect copy command is displayed, then edit to remove the "echo." to allow the copy to be performed. That way if it is not what you want you can corect it before it actually does anything.  After you have it working you can remove the pause too.  It's nice to have it now so you can see the results or error messages.

Comment: it says the system cannot find the file specified. what could be the reason. i tried below script 
SET srcdir=C:\data\PRODDB\dir\
SET tgtdir=c:\backupData
SET /A topcnt=3
SET /A cnt=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('DIR /A-D /OD /TW /B "%srcdir%"') DO (
  SET /A cnt+=1
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  IF !cnt! GTR !topcnt! (ENDLOCAL & GOTO :EOF)
  ENDLOCAL
  COPY "%srcdir%\%%F" "%tgtdir%"
)    I got the result but didn't understand the why there is a topcnt put in there.

Comment: C:\data\PRODDB\dir does not exist!

Comment: I am new to batch scripting,please bare with me. i want to create a automated script to copy the files which are in C:\data\PRODDB\dir based on date (which are created today) to c:\test and delete those files from d:\test after they are backed up by the backup software. thanks RGuggisberg .

Comment: Well you have quite a mess there.  It is hard to read as you have it posted now.  1. Mismatched parens. 2. You can not use %%F outside the FOR construct. 3. You should have the SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion prior to the FOR statement.  4. What are you doing with Cnt?  5. There will be cases where no copy is done.  6.  need a new explanation, as it seem you have changed the question.  7. My code should work if the folders exist.  Or at least I think there will be less problems with the code I posted than there is with what you last posted.

Comment: C:\data\PRODDB\dir exists and the c:\test directory exists on my system. but i don't know why it's not working.  Just copied the code ,removed the echo. and pause command and created the batch file                                                             @echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir C:\data\PRODDB\dir /B /A-D /O-D') do copy "%%a" c:\test & goto :Done
:Done
please let me know anything else to be done.

Comment: Put the pause back in there so you can see the error you are getting.  Only take it out after you have it working.  I tried it here and it is working for me.