# Move all files created today from network location to local drive

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

Using my below given script, I simply wanted to cut-paste all the .dat files created today from source to destination, where source is a network path.

```
@echo off

set datetime=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%_%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%

mkdir "D:\data\Backup\%datetime%"

net use L: \\10.xx.xx.xxx\shared\files /persistent:no
set source=L: \\10.xx.xx.xxx\shared\files

forfiles /P "%source%" /M *.dat /D +0 /C "cmd /c move @path D:\data\Backup\%datetime%"

net use L: /delete /y
```

BUT..its throwing `ERROR: The directory name is invalid.`

I am not getting why `FORFILES`is not accepting my network path as a source.

Please can somebody help me out here ?

I have no issue in using powershell as well.

Comment: Your source is `L: \\10.xx.xx.xxx\shared\files`.

Comment: @PetSerAl..yes thats my source.

Comment: Should it not be something like  `set "source=L:"` or `set "source=L:\files"`?

Comment: @MCND..Thank you so much !! after making it `set "source=L:"`, its working like a charm. :-) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell:

```
$src = '\\10.xx.xx.xxx\shared\files'
$dst = "D:\Data\Backup\$(Get-Date -f 'yyyyMMdd')"
mkdir $dst

Get-ChildItem $src -File | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).Date} | Copy-Item $dst
```

Comment: Is the hyphen before $ here a typo - `Copy-Item  -$dst`

Comment: Yes it is.  Fixed.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @KeithHill..I tested this one too and its working perfectly.