# Powershell- How to count files created today

Tags: powershell

I am somewhat new to powershell.
But I'm trying to count how many files were created today.
I have a job that creates files to a folder
and  id like to have a script count how many files were created today on the folder and after that id like to have a IF statement check that a certain number of files were created , if so write-host " Success there are # created today. " ELSE "Failure Only # were Created today".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28927807/move-all-files-created-today-from-network-location-to-local-drive gathers the files. You just need to count the results.

Comment: You have some answers here already but I wanted to point out that while you are new at this what you are asking here is already documented. If you having issues break it up into parts and look those up. `Get-ChildItem`, `Where-Object` and `Get-Date` are the main cmdlets used for this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
$folder="C:\Temp"

$r = Get-Childitem $folder * -Recurse | 
     Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date } | 
     Measure-Object

if ($r.Count -ge 100) {
    write-host "More than 100 files created under $folder" 
} else {
    write-host "Less than 100 files created under $folder"
}
```

Comment: The OP admits he is a new user. Using the full names for cmdlets and parameters would be a courtesy.

Comment: You might update this to reflect created time of file per the question, not last modified.

Answer (score 2):

```
$RequiredNumberOfFiles = 5
$a = (Get-ChildItem 'C:\temp' | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (get-date -format d)}).count
If ($a -eq $RequiredNumberOfFiles) {write-host "success"} else {write-host "fail"}
```

Comment: I like this solution, as it allows the use the value of $a variable if additional actions like email notifications are required.