# Previous day of file in .bat

Tags: batch-file

I have requirement to copy files of previous date from one folder to another.
I used below command to copy file for previous day which didn't work.
Any help on this is appreciated

```
@echo off
For /F "delims=" %%G In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).ToString('MMddyyyy')}"') Do Set "yesterday=%%G"
echo D | xcopy "D:\*.png" "D:\DNU" /D:yesterday /Y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to copy a file based on date modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802415/batch-file-to-copy-a-file-based-on-date-modified) You can also search this site for `[batch-file] copy file modified date` for other possible duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

From `xcopy /?`:

```
/D:m-d-y     Copies files changed on or after the specified date.
               If no date is given, copies only those files whose
               source time is newer than the destination time.
```

So it needs `m-d-y`, but you're feeding it with `MMddyyyy`.
Also you need put `%` around `yesterday` to use the value of this variable, so try this:

```
@echo off
For /F "delims=" %%G In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddDays(-1)).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy')}"') Do Set "yesterday=%%G"
echo D | xcopy "D:\*.png" "D:\DNU" /D:%yesterday% /Y
```

Comment: Hi Tiw, Thanks for the reply. I tried the given code. My file timestamp is 1/25/2019 10:36 PM CST. But, when I run the code, this file is copied in the folder as well. As it is today's file, it should not be copied. Also, even if I update AddDays(-1)) to AddDays(-2)) or AddDays(-3)), this file is getting copied. Please suggest

Comment: @BHP  `Copies files changed on or after the specified date`. this is what `xcopy` designd to do.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Do we have any command which juts picks yesterday's file instead of file on or after the specified date

Comment: @BHP  Check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802415/batch-file-to-copy-a-file-based-on-date-modified  Ken gave you.